# TextInputDialog only shown for the first time

Tags: java, javafx, awt

Refer to the code snippet below:

```
public class Application extends javafx.application.Application implements ActionListener {

  private java.awt.SystemTray tray;
  private java.awt.TrayIcon trayIcon;
  private java.awt.PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu();
  private java.awt.MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("My Item");

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    if (!SystemTray.isSupported())
      return;

    menuItem.addActionListener(this);
    popupMenu.add(menuItem);

    trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Title", popupMenu);
    tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    tray.add(trayIcon);
  } 

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
      Optional<String> result = new TextInputDialog().showAndWait();
      if(result.isPresent() && !result.get().isEmpty()){
        ...
      }
    })
  }
}
```

What happens is the dialog will only show once. The second or more time `actionPerformed()` is triggered, it won't popup and doesn't throw any exception.

I've tried using `Task`, `setOnSucceeded()` on that `Task`, and start a `Thread` based on that `Task`. Even worse, the dialog won't show up at all, and again, no error produced.

Comment: Can you show your imports? This doesn't really make sense: you're in a JavaFX application but registering an `ActionListener`?

Comment: @James_D You're right, both `MenuItem` and `ActionListener` are from java.awt. I know it isn't supposed to be so, but JavaFX does not yet implement cross-platform SystemTray like AWT does.

Comment: Can you make your example into a [MCVE]?

Comment: @James_D I updated the code but idk if it qualifies as minimal and complete and verifiable at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the following:

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
```

Otherwise the JavaFX runtime will shut down when you close your last window, hence why `Platform.runLater()` only works once for you

Snippet from [Platform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html):

> Sets the implicitExit attribute to the specified value. If this
>   attribute is true, the JavaFX runtime will implicitly shutdown when
>   the last window is closed; the JavaFX launcher will call the
>   Application.stop() method and terminate the JavaFX application thread.
>   If this attribute is false, the application will continue to run
>   normally even after the last window is closed, until the application
>   calls exit(). The default value is true.

Comment: Just figured that out too. Note that the AWT should also be done on the AWT Event Dispatch thread using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` (It seems to work without that, at least on my system, but it breaks AWT's threading rules.)